# c# dice game implementation

Tags: c#, dice

I'm stuck on how I can implement the code so when it compiles to one counter it displays one counter not 'counters' as a plural for only one counter. I need help on how I can implement that piece of code in to my code that I have given below.

```
namespace ReferralDG
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Even Minus Odd Game: ");
                Random rand = new Random();
                bool PlayAgain = false;
                do
                {
                    int numberOfDice = 0;
                    int totalOfDiceRolled = 0;
                    while (numberOfDice > 10 || numberOfDice < 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("How many dice do you wish to play     with? (Between 3 and 10?)");
                    numberOfDice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (numberOfDice > 10 || numberOfDice < 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the correct number
                    }
                    }

                    Console.Write("Dice rolls: ");
                    int evenTotal = 0;
                    int oddTotal = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
                    {                    
                        int diceRoll = rand.Next(1, 7);
                        if (diceRoll % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            evenTotal += diceRoll;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oddTotal += diceRoll;
                        }
                        totalOfDiceRolled += diceRoll;
                        Console.Write(diceRoll + " ");
                    }
                    int counters = evenTotal - oddTotal;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (counters > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You take " + counters + "     counters.");
                }
                else if (counters < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You give " + Math.Abs(counters) + " counters.");
                }
                else if (evenTotal == oddTotal)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Even total is equal to odd total");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No counters this game");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ");
                string playAgain = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                if (playAgain == "Y")
                {
                    PlayAgain = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    PlayAgain = false;
                }
            } while (PlayAgain);
       }
  }
```

}

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. Is `                        Console.WriteLine("You take " + counters + "     counter" + counters == 1 ? null : "s")` what you're after?

Comment: so basically when it compiles it tell the 'player' to either give or take counters based on the dice thrwon, so for example if it says that 'take 1 counters' i need to know how i can display 'take 1 counter' instead of counters when the plural isnt required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add additional `if`'s to your block.

```
if (counters > 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("You take " + counters + " counters.");
}
else if (counters > 0) // or if you rather counters == 1
{
    Console.WriteLine("You take " + counters + " counter.");
}
else if (counters < -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You give " + Math.Abs(counters) + " counters.");
}
else if (counters < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You give " + Math.Abs(counters) + " counter.");
}
else if (evenTotal == oddTotal)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Even total is equal to odd total");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No counters this game");
}
```

Another "simpler" solution is to just output it as `counter(s)`

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    namespace ReferralDG
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Even Minus Odd Game: ");
                Random rand = new Random();
                bool PlayAgain = false;
                do
                {
                    int numberOfDice = 0;
                    int totalOfDiceRolled = 0;
                    while (numberOfDice > 10 || numberOfDice < 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("How many dice do you wish to play     with? (Between 3 and 10?)");
                        numberOfDice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (numberOfDice > 10 || numberOfDice < 3)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the correct number");
                        }
                    }

                    Console.Write("Dice rolls: ");
                    int evenTotal = 0;
                    int oddTotal = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
                    {
                        int diceRoll = rand.Next(1, 7);
                        if (diceRoll % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            evenTotal += diceRoll;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oddTotal += diceRoll;
                        }
                        totalOfDiceRolled += diceRoll;
                        Console.Write(diceRoll + " ");
                    }
                    int counters = evenTotal - oddTotal;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (counters > 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You take " + counters + " counters.");
                    }
                    else if (counters > 0) // or if you rather counters == 1
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You take " + counters + " counter.");
                    }
                    else if (counters < -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You give " + Math.Abs(counters) + " counters.");
                    }
                    else if (counters < 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You give " + Math.Abs(counters) + " counter.");
                    }
                    else if (evenTotal == oddTotal)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Even total is equal to odd total");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No counters this game");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ");
                    string playAgain = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    if (playAgain == "Y")
                    {
                        PlayAgain = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PlayAgain = false;
                    }
                } while (PlayAgain);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, can you explain where in my code i'd need to put it in

Comment: This is your code. I just added an additional `if`. So just put this instead of your `if` `else` block

Comment: ok so this if you added should work on the basis of what i asked?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly then yes. If counters is 1 the output will be singular "counter", otherwise it will be the plural "counters"

Comment: yh thats correct, it should work for give or take counter??

Comment: so covering the take 1 counter and give 1 counter??

Comment: Ok, then you need to add an additional `if`. See my updated answer. If you feel like you can handle it though, I suggest doing it as @Matz Reckeweg suggested as it is more flexible and less messy

Comment: i find your way better but i did just try running it and it still does 'take 1 counters'

Comment: can you try running it please and see

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to run it at the moment. But I can see no possibility in my code writing  'take 1 counters'. Check your code again

Comment: i have checked it

Comment: i know your code doesnt show it but thew compiler doesnt anticipate it

Answer (score 1):

you could use the if shorthand `statement ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;` to set the right string values. and put everything in a function like that

```
    private static void printCounters(int counters,bool take) {
        counters = Math.Abs(counters);
        string msg1 = take ? "You take " : "You give ";
        string msg2 = counters == 1 ? " counter." : " counters.";
        Console.WriteLine( msg1 + counters + msg2);
    }
```

this has the advantage that you can easily call `printCounters(counters,true)` if you take and `printCounters(counters,give)` if you give

Comment: this is good however its too fancy for me to include, thanks for helping though

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow Sam!

So when you write the counters to the screen, you want it to write singular if their is a single counter, and plural if there are more than 1? I also assume we want this to work no matter if the counter is positive or negative.

Instead of adding a couple more branches to your if statement, we could use [string.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) and an [Inline If statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

In this case, it would look something like this:

```
 // Console.WriteLine("You take " + counters + "     counters.");
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("You take {0}     counter{1}.", counters, Math.Abs(counters) == 1 ? "" : "s"));
```

This is really just a way of writing multiple "else ifs", as you still have added a branching statement. My way, it is in-line instead of taking up more space vertically.

If you wanted to get even more fancy, you could use an IIF to set the "give" or "take" as well:

```
if (counters != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("You {0} {1}     counter{2}.",
        counters > 0 ? "take" : "give",
        counters, 
        Math.Abs(counters) == 1 ? "" : "s"
        ));
}
else if (evenTotal == oddTotal)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Even total is equal to odd total");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No counters this game");
}
```

Read up on the links, see what works best for you!

Comment: @Matz Reckeweg beat me to the punch. I took too long typing out a novel.

We have essentially the same answer with his being more reusable.